# Is there a WPF library with chord-graphs?

Tags: library, charts, wpf

I am building an application in WPF and I would like to implement a chord graph (like these https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/chord_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png). Is there a library (NUGET package)